# How to step forward/backward a few seconds in DaVinci resolve timeline with a hotkey?

Tags: video-editing

It is possible to step one frame or second in DaVinci Resolve by pressing left/right or shift+left/right. But is it possible to step, say, 5 seconds or 30 seconds?

Maybe you know if it is possible to add custom commands for stepping more than one second at a time in "Keyboard Customizations -> Command -> Playback"?

Answer (score 3):

You can step any number of minutes/seconds/frames you like by tapping  <kbd>=</kbd>  then `+`, `-` `interval` or a direct time, then Enter.

eg
5 seconds forwards… `=+5.0`  [image]

5 frames back `=-5` [image]

To a specific time `=1.3.22` [image]

Digits without a decimal are considered as frames & it will roll-over if more than one second of frames, ie 50f gives 2s @ 25fps.
This is all much easier if you have a 10-key, of course.

Comment: I use this myself, but the problem is: it is more efficient to press shift and right arrow 5 times to skip 5 seconds than pressing "=", "+" and then "5" followed by 2 zeros and finally "enter". That is why I am asking about the ability to hotkey this combination.

Comment: There's no single hotkey, nor did you mention in your question what you'd already discovered. btw, to move 5s, `= + 5 . Enter` will do it.